# Custom PHP Extensions on Azure

Tags: php, azure, zend-framework2

I am deploying a Zend2 application to a Azure Website with php5.5. The application uses the php_intl extension. I have put the extension in the indicated place bin/php_intl.php and set an app setting to PHP_EXTENSIONS = bin/php_intl.php. The phpinfo() tells me the setting is loaded however the extension is not.
Is it at all possible to load an extension this way? Or only by deploying your own php-cgi.exe?

Comment: Are you want to create new PHP extension?

Comment: no php_intl is a standard php extension for internationalization, in azure it simply isn't activate by default.

Comment: I found out the extension isn't loading the uci* libraries it is depending on. I placed them along site the dll, but that doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Intl is a wrapper for ICU library.

ICU is a mature, widely used set of C/C++ and Java libraries providing Unicode and Globalization support for software applications. ICU is widely portable and gives applications the same results on all platforms and between C/C++ and Java software.

Look for install here: http://site.icu-project.org/download/48#ICU4C

Answer (score 0):

Weird, I have multiple ZF2 applications running on Azure Websites but I never had to add the intl extension specifically. Just deploy without anything special.